# oracle - mixing SQL code with PLSQL when no bindings in WHERE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, binding, plsql

I am trying to write a very simple sql script:
select * from table_X;
and I would like to see the results in oracle sqlplus, if there are any. These results are important for further analysis.
Also to mention, it depends, how many tables were created originally, so chances are that table_X may not be in the database at all. However I want to avoid getting an error, when parsing, that table_X doesn't exist, while running that script above.

So I was trying to wrap that SQL into some PLSQL dynamic code, like this:

```
Define table_X="MY_TAB"
    DECLARE
       stmt_     VARCHAR2(2000);
       exist_ number := 0;
       CURSOR table_exist IS
         SELECT 1
           FROM user_tables
          WHERE table_name = '&table_X';
    BEGIN
       OPEN table_exist;
       FETCH table_exist INTO exist_;
       CLOSE table_exist;

       IF exist_ = 1 THEN
          stmt_ := 'SELECT * FROM &table_X';
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt_;
       ELSE
          dbms_output.put_line('This functionality is not installed.');
       END IF;
    END;
/
```

1. Why I cannot see any result (records), if there is data in MY_TAB? Do I really need to bind some columns and use ex. dbms_output to be able to see some information?
2. Is there any simple way to query a table without getting 'ORA-00942: table or view does not exist'
   if that table doesn't exist (ideally using SQL only)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried adding `set serveroutput on` at the begining of your script? http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/serveroutput.html

Comment: Also, your question #2 should be moved to a whole separate StackOverflow question since it's not really related to your output question.

Answer (score 0):

like this if you want it in sqlplus:

```
SQL> var c refcursor;
SQL> create or replace function get_table(p_tab in varchar2)
  2  return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4  v_r sys_refcursor;
  5  NO_TABLE exception;
  6  pragma exception_init(NO_TABLE, -942);
  7  begin
  8    open v_r for 'select * from ' || dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(p_tab);
  9    return v_r;
 10  exception
 11    when NO_TABLE
 12    then
 13      open v_r for select 'NO TABLE ' || p_tab as oops from dual;
 14      return v_r;
 15  end;
 16  /

Function created.

SQL> exec :c := get_table('DUAL2');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print c

OOPS
-----------------------------------------
NO TABLE DUAL2

SQL>
SQL> exec :c := get_table('DUAL');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print c

D
-
X
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `execute immediate 'query'` you could use `execute immediate 'query' bulk collect into` and then loop over it and use `dbms_output` to print it.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm